# Проверить заполнение ListBox C#

Tags: c#, winforms

В общем, есть ListBox, мне нужно проверить, если в нем есть элементы, то должна выполниться функция, если он пустой, то ничего не должно происходить.

Вот код:

```
private void MusicPlayerButtonNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(MusicPlayerListBox.Items != 0)
    {
        if (Main.Files.Count > Main.CurrentTrackNumber + 1)
        {
            ClassMusicPlayer.Play(Main.Files[++Main.CurrentTrackNumber], ClassMusicPlayer.Volume);
            ClassMusicPlayer.EndPlayList = false;
        }
        else
            ClassMusicPlayer.EndPlayList = true;
        if (ClassMusicPlayer.EndPlayList)
        {
            MusicPlayerButtonStop_Click(this, new EventArgs());
            MusicPlayerListBox.SelectedIndex = Main.CurrentTrackNumber = 0;
            ClassMusicPlayer.EndPlayList = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Ошибка в строке: if(MusicPlayerListBox.Items != 0).
Как мне сделать проверку?

Comment: WinForms или WPF?

Comment: текст ошибки можно опубликовать?

Comment: @Gardes: `MusicPlayerListBox.Items != 0` — несоответствие типов, думаю.

Comment: @VladD WinForm. Да, не соответствие типов

Comment: Ну так понятно. `MusicPlayerListBox.Items` — это ж не число.

Comment: @VladD спасибо) прочел и сразу понял что надо добавить Count)

Comment: @Sanvirtus: Пожалуйста!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private void MusicPlayerButtonNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(MusicPlayerListBox.Items.Count != 0)
    {
        if (Main.Files.Count > Main.CurrentTrackNumber + 1)
        {
            ClassMusicPlayer.Play(Main.Files[++Main.CurrentTrackNumber], ClassMusicPlayer.Volume);
            ClassMusicPlayer.EndPlayList = false;
        }
        else
            ClassMusicPlayer.EndPlayList = true;
        if (ClassMusicPlayer.EndPlayList)
        {
            MusicPlayerButtonStop_Click(this, new EventArgs());
            MusicPlayerListBox.SelectedIndex = Main.CurrentTrackNumber = 0;
            ClassMusicPlayer.EndPlayList = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Для того чтобы не строить египетские пирамиды из вложенных блоков условия, можно изменить условие на противоположное и выйти из метода. ИМХО, код более читаемый, что проще и вам, и тем кто будет на этот код смотреть. Тоесть, первый блок условия заменить на
if(MusicPlayerListBox.Items.Count == 0) { return; }
а дальше по вашему тексту. И пропадает целый уровень вложенности.

Comment: @test123 спасибо, учту. действительно так выглядит намного лучше)

Answer (score 0):

```
if (MusicPlayerListBox.Items.Count > 0)
```

Comment: И чем этот ответ отличается от другого, уже существующего ответа?